# Is there a Netflix video library?

Tags: java, netflix

Is there a Java library to download movie data from Netflix? I'm not just talking about the tags, but the actual movie itself. I've tried Googling it but I can't find anything.

Edit: I want to stream it, not download it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: An API to download the movie? Not a chance.

Comment: It's probably a bit too late but you can try to code your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Netflix films can't be downloaded. 
The movies available on Netflix' on-demand service are there for streaming. Neither Netflix nor the movies' copyright holders want to give you a permanent copy of your own.

Comment: @ShawnShroyer An API for streaming is one tiny step away from downloading... answer is still no.

Comment: @shawn Plex just runs Netflix's own player, not any API netflix exposes. The only way to get Netflix via Java is either to implement a silverlight player or crack netflix's DRM.